# Python - KeyError: '\n'

Tags: python, keyerror

Right, so I downloaded a Python program to decode DNA sequences. It was meant for Python 2.7 but whatever I do pip installs it into Python 3.6. So I added the brackets for the print functions, and it becomes usable. Command line code below:

```
kevin@Kevin-Jia:~$ sudo pip install file2dna
Collecting file2dna
  Using cached file2dna-0.4.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: file2dna
  Running setup.py install for file2dna ... done
Successfully installed file2dna-0.4
kevin@Kevin-Jia:~$ sudo nano /usr/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/dna/dna.py
kevin@Kevin-Jia:~$ dna
usage: dna [-h] [-e | -s | -d | -j] file
dna: error:  the following arguments are required: file
kevin@Kevin-Jia:~$ dna -d code.dna
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dna", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('file2dna==0.4', 'console_scripts', 'dna')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dna/dna.py", line 379, in 
  main
    dna.decode(args.file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dna/dna.py", line 49, in 
  decode
    s4 = self.__S5_to_S4(s5)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dna/dna.py", line 294, in 
  __S5_to_S4   
    s4 = dna_inv_table[s5[i]][s5[i-1]] + s4
KeyError: '\n'
kevin@Kevin-Jia:~$
```

Code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import binascii
import csv
from random import randint
import os
import math
import zipfile
import sys
import argparse

class DNA(object):
    """
    This class implements four main methods:
        encode(file): encode an arbitrary file in DNA form as described
                    in Nature's article.
        encode_split(file): encode and prepare file for sequencing.
        decode(file): decode file from DNA.
        decode_join(file): decode splitted file.
    """

    # Huffman code dictionary
    code = {}

    # Dictionary with files 2-trits
    files_trits = {}

    def __init__(self):
        """ Populates the Huffman code dictionary """

        # Read the dictionary from data/huff3.dict
        # I made this file from the View_huff3.cd.new.correct
        huff_dict = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "data/huff3.dict"), "r")
        csv_reader = csv.reader(huff_dict, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_reader:
            self.code[row[0]] = row[1]

    def encode(self, input_file):
        """ Encode input_file in an DNA string """

        s1 = self.__S0_to_S1(input_file)
        s4 = self.__S1_to_S4(s1)
        s5 = self.__S4_to_S5(s4)
        open(input_file + '.dna', 'w').write(s5)

    def decode(self, input_file):
        """ Decode file in an DNA string """
        s5 = open(input_file, 'r').read()
        s4 = self.__S5_to_S4(s5)
        s0 = self.__S4_to_S0(s4)
        # Save s0 after conversion from hexadecimal to bytes
        open(input_file[:-4]+'.decoded', 'wb').write(binascii.unhexlify(s0))

    def decode_join(self, input_file):
        """ Decode and join DNA zip file into DNA string """
        Findex = self.__Files_to_Findex(input_file)
        Fi = self.__Findex_to_Fi(Findex)
        s5 = self.__Fi_to_S5(Fi)
        s4 = self.__S5_to_S4(s5)
        s0 = self.__S4_to_S0(s4)
        # Save s0 after conversion from hexadecimal to bytes
        open(input_file[:-13]+'.decoded', 'wb').write(binascii.unhexlify(s0))

    def encode_split(self, input_file):
        """ Encode file in many overlapping DNA string. Returns a zip file """

        s1 = self.__S0_to_S1(input_file)
        s4 = self.__S1_to_S4(s1)
        s5 = self.__S4_to_S5(s4)
        F = self.__S5_to_Fi(s5)
        Findex = self.__Fi_to_Findex(F, input_file)
        self.__Findex_to_Files(Findex, input_file)
        return Findex

    def __S0_to_S1(self, input_file):

        # Update 2-trits file dictionary (for later use: if more than one file)
        trit = self.__base10_to_base3(len(self.files_trits))
        trit = '0'  * (2 - len(trit)) + trit
        self.files_trits[input_file] = trit
        # Concatenate byte by byte to s1 (after Huffman codification)
        s1 = ""
        with open(input_file, 'rb') as f:
            byte = f.read(1)
            while byte:
                s1 = s1 + self.code[str(int(binascii.hexlify(byte), 16))]
                byte = f.read(1)
        return s1

    def __S1_to_S4(self, s1):

        # Compute s2
        n = len(s1)
        s2 = self.__base10_to_base3(n)
        s2 = '0' * (20 - len(s2)) + s2

        # Compute s3
        s3 = '0' * (-(n + len(s2) % 25) % 25)

        # Compute s4
        s4 = s1 + s3 + s2
        return s4

    def __S4_to_S5(self, s4):

        # Create table
        dna_table = {
            'A': ['C', 'G', 'T'],
            'C': ['G', 'T', 'A'],
            'G': ['T', 'A', 'C'],
            'T': ['A', 'C', 'G']
        }

        s5 = ''
        s5 = s5 + dna_table['A'][int(s4[0])]
        for c in s4[1:]:
            s5 = s5 + dna_table[s5[-1]][int(c)]

        return s5

    def __S5_to_Fi(self, s5):
        n = len(s5)
        F = []
        for i in range(0, n/25 - 3):
            # Reverse if odd
            if i % 2 == 1:
                F.append(self.__reverse_complement(s5[25*i:25*i+100]))
            else:
                F.append(s5[25*i:25*i+100])
        return F

    def __Fi_to_Findex(self, F, input_file):

        # Indexed segments
        Findex = []

        # File ID
        ID = self.files_trits[input_file]

        # Create table
        dna_table = {
            'A': ['C', 'G', 'T'],
            'C': ['G', 'T', 'A'],
            'G': ['T', 'A', 'C'],
            'T': ['A', 'C', 'G']
        }

        # For each segment compute the IX
        for i in range(0, len(F)):
            i3 = self.__base10_to_base3(i)
            i3 = '0' * (12 - len(i3)) + i3
            P = (int(ID[1-1]) + int(i3[1-1]) + int(i3[3-1]) +
                int(i3[5-1]) + int(i3[7-1]) + int(i3[9-1]) + int(i3[11-1])) % 3
            IX = ID + i3 + str(P)

            ix = ''
            ix = ix + dna_table[F[i][-1]][int(IX[0])]
            for c in IX[1:]:
                ix = ix + dna_table[ix[-1]][int(c)]

            if F[i][0] == 'A':
                F[i] = 'T' + F[i]
            elif F[i][0] == 'T':
                F[i] = 'A' + F[i]
            else:
                if randint(0,1) == 0:
                    F[i] = 'A' + F[i]
                else:
                    F[i] = 'T' + F[i]

            if ix[-1] == 'C':
                ix = ix + 'G'
            elif ix[-1] == 'G':
                ix = ix + 'C'
            else:
                if randint(0,1) == 0:
                    ix = ix + 'G'
                else:
                    ix = ix + 'C'

            Findex.append(F[i] + ix)

        return Findex

    def __Findex_to_Files(self, Findex, input_file):
        temp_dir = input_file +'.splitted'
        if not os.path.exists(temp_dir):
            os.makedirs(temp_dir)
        zf = zipfile.ZipFile(temp_dir +'.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

        # Necessary number of leading zeros
        n0 = int(math.log(len(Findex), 10) + 1)

        i = 0
        for f in Findex:
            fragment_file = "{0}.{1:0{2}d}".format(os.path.basename(input_file), i, n0) 
            open(fragment_file, 'w').write(f)
            zf.write(fragment_file)
            os.remove(fragment_file)
            i = i + 1
        os.rmdir(temp_dir)

    def __Files_to_Findex(self, input_file):

        # Remove the .zip
        temp_dir = input_file[:-4]

        # Extract files to temp_dir
        zipfile.ZipFile(input_file, 'r').extractall(temp_dir)

        Findex = []
        for f in os.listdir(temp_dir):
            fragment_file = temp_dir + os.sep + f
            Findex.append(open(fragment_file, 'r').read())
            os.remove(fragment_file)

        os.rmdir(temp_dir)

        return Findex

    def __Findex_to_Fi(self, Findex):

        # Create inverse table
        dna_inv_table = {
            'A': {'T': '0', 'G': '1', 'C': '2'},
            'C': {'A': '0', 'T': '1', 'G': '2'},
            'G': {'C': '0', 'A': '1', 'T': '2'},
            'T': {'G': '0', 'C': '1', 'A': '2'}
        }

        F = [''] * len(Findex)
        for Fi in Findex:

            # Check if reverse complemented
            if Fi[0] != 'T' and Fi[0] != 'A':
                Fi = self.__reverse_complement(Fi)

            # Remove prepended A/T and appended C/G
            Fi = Fi[1:116] # Prior lenght of Fi is 117

            # Extract ix (last 15) n DNA format
            ix = Fi[-15:]
            Fi = Fi[:-15]

            # Convert ix to trits (IX)
            lastFi = Fi[-1]
            IX = dna_inv_table[ix[0]][lastFi]
            for i in range(1, 15):
                IX = IX + dna_inv_table[ix[i]][ix[i-1]]

            # Extract ID
            ID = IX[:2]

            # Extract i3 and i
            i3 = IX[2:len(IX)-1]
            i = self.__base3_to_base10(i3)

            # Checksum error
            P = int(IX[-1])
            Pexpected = (int(ID[1-1]) + int(i3[1-1]) + int(i3[3-1]) + 
                        int(i3[5-1]) + int(i3[7-1]) + int(i3[9-1]) + int(i3[11-1])) % 3
            if P != Pexpected:
                print("Corrupted segment:\nID = %s\ni = %d") %(ID, i)
            else:
                # Save Fi
                if i % 2 == 1:
                    F[i] = self.__reverse_complement(Fi)
                else:
                    F[i] = Fi
        return F

    def __Fi_to_S5(self, Fi):

        # In real applications we should check if the overlapping
        # parts are equal. I won't do that for now

        s5 = Fi[0][0:75]
        for f in Fi:
            s5 = s5 + f[-25:]
        return s5

    def __S5_to_S4(self, s5):

        # Create inverse table
        dna_inv_table = {
            'A': {'T': '0', 'G': '1', 'C': '2'},
            'C': {'A': '0', 'T': '1', 'G': '2'},
            'G': {'C': '0', 'A': '1', 'T': '2'},
            'T': {'G': '0', 'C': '1', 'A': '2'}
        }

        s4 = ''
        for i in range(len(s5) -1, 0,-1):
            s4 = dna_inv_table[s5[i]][s5[i-1]] + s4
        s4 = dna_inv_table[s5[0]]['A'] + s4

        return s4

    def __S4_to_S0(self, s4):

        # s2 is the last 20 trits
        s2 = s4[-20:]

        # n = len(s1) is s2 converted to base 10 
        n = self.__base3_to_base10(s2)

        # s1 is the first n trits
        s1 = s4[:n]

        # Time to convert s1 from trits to bytes in s0
        inverted_code = dict([v,k] for k,v in self.code.items())
        s0 = ''
        i = 0
        while i != n:
            if s1[i:i+5] in inverted_code.keys():
                s0 = s0 + ''.join('%02x' % int(inverted_code[s1[i:i+5]]))
                i = i + 5
            else:
                s0 = s0 + ''.join('%02x' % int(inverted_code[s1[i:i+6]]))
                i = i + 6

        return s0

    def __base10_to_base3(self,n):
        """ Input: int and Output: str """
        if n == 0:
            return '0'

        s = ''
        while n != 0:
            s =  str((n % 3)) + s
            n = n/3
        return s

    def __base3_to_base10(self,n):
        """ Input: str and Output: int """
        n = int(n)
        if n == 0:
            return 0

        res = 0
        b = 1
        while n != 0:
            res = res + (n % 10) * b
            n = n/10
            b = 3 * b
        return res
        # return int(n , 3) <= Hahaha

    def __reverse_complement(self,s):
        reverse = ''

        complement_dict = {'A': 'T', 'T': 'A', 'C':'G', 'G': 'C'}

        for c in s:
            reverse = complement_dict[c] + reverse

        return  reverse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='dna')
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    group.add_argument('-e', help='encode file and save it as .dna', action="store_true")
    group.add_argument('-s', help='encode file and save it as .splitted.zip', action="store_true")
    group.add_argument('-d', help='decode .dna file and save as .decoded', action="store_true")
    group.add_argument('-j', help='decode .splitted.zip file and save it as .decoded', action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument('file', type=str, help='File to be encoded/decoded.')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    dna = DNA()
    if args.e:
        dna.encode(args.file)
    elif args.s:
        dna.encode_split(args.file)
    elif args.d:
        if args.file[-4:] != '.dna':
            print("I only decode files terminated in .dna!")
            sys.exit(1)
        dna.decode(args.file)
    elif args.j:
        if args.file[-13:] != '.splitted.zip':
            print("I only decode and join files terminated in .splitted.zip!")
            sys.exit(1)
        dna.decode_join(args.file)
    else:
        parser.print_help()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So does anyone know how to fix this error - I've tried everything?

Comment: We can't help you if we don't see the code.

Comment: use `pip2 install`... ? it's asking for trouble installing a Py 2 package on Py 3, you can't just add parantheses to your `print` statements and expect it to work!

Comment: I edited it to show the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file "code.dna" does not conform to the syntax, which the python scripts expects. The file contains a newline character ("\n"), which the programmer of the script did not consider. It might be that the file "code.dna" uses Windows style newline, whereas the script is now ran on Linux? But that's just a guess. The data file could be completely different from what the script expects.

Comment: i removed newlines on my file and it still doesnt work

Comment: Try it with one of the example data files, that came with the script, e.g.: https://github.com/allanino/DNA/blob/master/examples/DNA_versions/View_huff3.cd.new.dna

Comment: thanks i tried it and it now works :) could somebody tag this as resolved